# How to set listener for click event which is outside of Spinner?

Tags: android

Now I have a Spinner which has been clicked and the DropDownView is showing, I want to click outside of the Spinner and do something.

How can I listen to this click event which is outside of spinner?

I try some ways(such as override `dispatchTouchEvent()` of Activity) to solve this question, but I found that it is impossible to execute method `dispatchTouchEvent()` when DropDownView is showing:

```
//Kotlin
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    //do something I want
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User custom dialog for spinner and make dialog.setCancelable(true) for outside click .

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#3E80B4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="This is spinner"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/size_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/size_entries" />



</LinearLayout>
```